# Can AWS rekognition detect a table within an image and allow me to ingest into a dynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rekognition

I have a lot of documents in offline books. It's in table format and I don't want to manually input these tables into a dynamoDB table. Can I use AWS rekognition to help me here OR I should look at some other service ?

Answer (score 0):

Rekognition won't generally do a good job at this. AWS has a new OCR service called Textract. It's able to figure out tables and forms (content and structure).

You can join the preview at https://aws.amazon.com/textract/